# Getting 3 different errors when using Google.GData for importing GMail Contacts

Tags: c#, webforms, google-api, gdata

My apologies for a lame descriptive question.

So I am trying to use GData to import contacts from GMail, I have followed a couple tutorials and I had it working once. *Now I am trying to implement it in another web application but I keep getting 3 errors.*

I have downloaded and installed the Google Data API and have added the references to the project and have written a seperate class that will return the GMail contacts.

***As of the moment my code is this (yes, I know I haven't populated the dataset yet)***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Google.GData.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.Contacts;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace GSDataCollection.Models
{
    public class GetGmailContacts
    {
        public DataSet GottenGMailContacts(string email, string password)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add("GMailContacts");
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("EmailId");
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Name");

            RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings("MyApp", email, password);
            rs.AutoPaging = true;

            ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);
            Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();           
                foreach (Contact contacts in f.Entries)
                {
                    foreach (EMail email in contacts.Emails)
                    {
                        DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
                        row["EmailId"] = email.Address.ToString();
                        row["Name"] = contact.Title.ToString();

                        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }   

            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

***Right now I have these 3 errors.***

> The type 'GSDataCollection.Contact' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Google.GData.Client.Feed'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'GSDataCollection.Contact' to 'Google.GData.Client.Entry'.
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Google.GData.Client.Feed' to 'Google.GData.Client.Feed'
>
> 'GSDataCollection.Contact' does not contain a definition for 'Emails' and no extension method 'Emails' accepting a first argument of type 'GSDataCollection.Contact' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have followed the tutorials that I have used before to do this and everything worked fine, *but now that I am trying to implement it into a new project, its giving me a hassle.*

Any idea's on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I should have been doing this..

```
Feed<Google.Contacts.Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
```

But then another error arose and that was I was getting a 404 error. After some digging around I found out that you can't import contacts this way anymore and have to use OAuth. This was changed this year, I think the post said May 26, 2015. If I find the post again then I'll post.